# Image isn't being cut off at end of page

Tags: html, css

At the bottom of this webpage there are two images that  extend the webpage:
[image]

I want to cut the webpage off to the dark-blue portion. When I say `html { overflow: hidden }` in the css it works, but you cant scroll at all when you make the page smaller. How do I cut off to only the blue part while cropping the images?

Link to github repo: https://github.com/dhruvRamaswamy/Miro-Landing-page

Comment: Throw the images in a container of some kind and apply overflow: hidden to the container

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. I think its because the images are absolute positioned or something like that

Comment: You can use clip-path, that might work

Comment: Please put code direct into your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example